# How can I use moment js to parse this date string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to process my facebook data that I downloaded. The dates look something like this

```
 "Wednesday, 15 June 2011 at 20:04 UTC-03"
```

How can I parse it. My failed attempt:

```
 moment(date).format('YYYY HH:mm')
```

Thanks

Comment: You should give the documentation a whirl:  http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: given it a whirl, couldn't get my head round it

Comment: The link I pasted takes you directly to the relevant section of the documentation.  There are even examples there that should help you get your head around it.  Or wait 3 minutes for someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on parsing is insufficient and does not show you how to parse the day of week.  You can use the following format: `"dddd, DD MMMM YYYY [at] hh:mm"` like so.

```
moment("Wednesday, 15 June 2011 at 20:04 UTC-03", "dddd, DD MMMM YYYY [at] hh:mm").format("YYYY HH:mm")
```